# Orientation Issue with photo browser

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using [KTPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser). Can any one tell me why when I use the TabBarSample of this code in my project, I am not able to make the photos work for landscape? The photos always display in portrait mode as my project only runs in portrait. How do I solve this issue? I have added the following

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate { 
    return YES; 
}
```

in `SDWebImageRootViewController.m` but still no luck.

Please can anyone download [this](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser) and see why the TabBarSample(project) not working for the landscape ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: @iO Adding XCode as a tag tells people that this question is related to XCode, the IDE used for iOS development, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: Check all viewController's in the TabBarController supports orientation

Comment: i am working with ios6 so i added -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate { 
    return YES; 
} in the all viewcontroller's but still no luck ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend Ryan's answer for anyone else who read this.

But in this particular case, what happened was the UITabBarController is not being set as the root view controller in the app window. I can only guess that this worked differently before iOS 6 (that Github project is 3 years old). Therefore you got this message in the log:

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

To solve this, change this line in your app delegate:

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

To this:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

And then as Anill said, we need to make sure all of the view controllers in the tab bar agree to rotate.

Answer (score 2):

You need two lines for iOS6 rotation. You say yes I want your to auto rotate, and here are the supported orientations. Add these to all your viewControllers.

```
// iOS5 Rotation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

// iOS6 Rotation
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

You may also need to go into your Project Settings and make sure your plist supports landscape orientations too.

Comment: Its not a secret art. If every view in your app has this it WILL rotate. There is another view somewhere without it. Since you're using a third party library I'd be willing to be its inside it. Are you sure ktphotobrowser supports landscape itself?

Comment: sorry but i am not sure of that .. and if it does not supports how do i make it support as also i can't see the NSLog message that i put in the BOOl method on the console ... ?

Comment: Go check our Enrico's answer. He has found a bug in the sample code.

Comment: KTPhotoBrowser supports lanscape :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved
Add following code to

```
SDWebImageRootViewController.m  
LocalImageRootViewController.m  
FlickrRootViewController.m


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
return YES;
}
```