# Orientation Issue in iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, orientation

I am working in iPad application, Using UITabBarController to create this application like four tabbar are A,B,C and D. All tabbar set Landscape orientation, When i select 3rd tab and press Submit Button to hide tabbar at the time and navigate to another screen (Pdf_reader.m).
I have set all the orientation in (Pdf_reader.m) class and its navigate portrait, then click back barbutton to go ClassC.m showing portrai mode, but i want Pdf_reader screen only rotate all orienatation, all the tabbar set Landscape mode, How to fix this issue?

```
ClassC.m //Hide tabbar

-(void)Submit
{

 PDFExampleViewController *open = [[PDFExampleViewController alloc]init];
 open.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:open animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626633/orientation-issue-with-photo-browser). There are a few things you have to watch out.